# -webkit-box not work in IE,but work in chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer

-webkit-box not work  in IE,so this code work in IE.

:p tag

```
<p class="company__note">職種商品企画・プランニング、人事・労務、営業（個人向け・新規開拓中心）、営業（個人向け・得意先中心）、営業（企業向け・新規開拓中心）、営業（企業向け・得意先中心）、販売・サービススタッフ、店長（店舗経営など）、店舗開発、総合職、営業職、管理系職種（経理・人事・総務）sadsadsadasd</p>
```

:css

```
.company__note {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

**Above code**
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical; is not work in IE.

Comment: IE is not webkit....

Comment: As other community members had already informed you that [webkit-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-flex), [webkit-line-clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) and [webkit-box-orient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient) are not supported in the IE browser. this is the reason that it is not working in the IE browser. You can show us what actual result you want to get by using the IE browser. We can try to provide suggestions for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not working because IE is not webkit based browser.
Also IE doesn’t support line-clamp https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp 
 Try to avoid using -webkit-box and -webkit-box-orient, because these properties are non-standard
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-flex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient